# Font Awesome 5 icons not working in Vuetify with Nuxt

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, font-awesome, nuxt.js

I have followed the installation procedure prescribed in the Vuetify to use the Font Awesome icons in my `Nuxt` app.

https://vuetifyjs.com/en/customization/icons/#install-font-awesome-5-icons

However, the icons are not working. Here is my template code.

```
<v-btn v-for="icon in icons" :key="icon" class="mx-3" icon>
  <v-icon size="24px">
    {{ icon }}
  </v-icon>
</v-btn>
```

Here is the script code.

```
<script>
export default {
  name: 'Footer',
  data () {
    return {
      icons: [
        'fab fa-facebook',
        'fab fa-twitter',
        'fab fa-linkedin',
        'fab fa-google-plus',
        'fab fa-instagram'
      ]
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use CLI to install the Font Awesome icons

```
npm install --save @fortawesome/fontawesome-free
```

Add the CSS in the `nuxt.config.js` file

```
css: [
  '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.css'
],
```

Comment: Thanks, this solution works for me. @nuxt/bulma have same problem with fa icons